# To_date without format warning

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

After I complier my code, I get some warnings/hints that I need to get rid of. the first one is To_date without Format issue

```sql
_current_end := to_date(((to_number(yearStatus)) ||
                                          MonthAndDay),
                                          'YYYYMMDD');
```

I get the error "Hint TO_DATE without format in Procedure_Name" but I thought the YYYYMMDD would have take it away.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Which database do you use?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 surplus parentheses:

This small block works fine:

```
Declare
  yearStatus   varchar2(4):='2019';
  MonthAndDay  varchar2(4):='1101';
  current_end  date;
begin
  current_end:=to_date(to_number(yearStatus)||MonthAndDay,
                       'YYYYMMDD'
                       );
  Dbms_Output.Put_Line('current_end='||to_char(current_end,'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'));
End;
/
```

output is:

```
PL/SQL block, executed in 62 ms
current_end=2019-11-01 00:00:00
Total execution time 343 ms
```

Answer (score 1):

More parentheses than necessary does not makes things better. PL/SQL is not Lisp (where more parentheses than are necessary are not good either :-) - you don't have to surround every function invocation with parentheses. Also, IMO too much whitespace is as bad as too little.

```
current_end := TO_DATE(TO_NUMBER(yearStatus) || MonthAndDay, 'YYYYMMDD');
```

is easier to read and understand, at least to my eye.

[dbfiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=55e1f926558fd3d4c91146a75d524698)

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your parentheses (yes, you could remove some but it is not invalid syntax to leave them there); however, you cannot have a variable starting with an underscore in PL/SQL.

```sql
DECLARE
  yearStatus  CHAR(4) := '2019';
  MonthAndDay CHAR(4) := '0101';
  current_end DATE;
BEGIN
  current_end := to_date(((to_number(yearStatus)) ||
                                          MonthAndDay),
                                          'YYYYMMDD');
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( current_end );
END;
/
```

Outputs:

> ```
> 2019-01-01T00:00:00
> ```

However, if you want to simplify the code then you can get rid of the `TO_NUMBER` call as the `||` concatenation operator is going to implicitly re-cast it back to a string:

```sql
DECLARE
  yearStatus  CHAR(4) := '2019';
  MonthAndDay CHAR(4) := '0101';
  current_end DATE;
BEGIN
  current_end := to_date(yearStatus || MonthAndDay, 'YYYYMMDD');
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( current_end );
END;
/
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e07c7683a0749ad96ce3e1fa20b539bb)*

Comment: If variable **yearStatus** is of type number, there is no need to use **to_number** function.

Comment: @alvalongo There is no need to use `TO_NUMBER` even if it is a string.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can remove the string concatenation all together.

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'yyyy/mm/dd"T"hh24:mi:ss';
declare
  yearstatus  char(4) := '2019';
  current_end date;
begin
  current_end := trunc(to_date(yearstatus,'yyyy'),'yyyy');
  dbms_output.put_line( current_end );
end;
```

Is that any better? Your choice.